# When to bring potted calamondin tree indoor?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, leaves

I have a potted calamondin tree (calamansi). I had to bring it to the balcony in summer because it does not fit on a window sill and it was too hot to keep the curtains open all day. Now I noticed that it started to shed leaves more than usual. Those are all old leaves from the bottom of the foliage, mostly with yellow tint. The balcony is glass-shielded, but the temperature is somewhat lower and the day is shorter. Can I assume that it just reacts to the oncoming autumn? This reminds me that I will need to bring it indoor eventually before winter comes. When can I bring it indoor? When should I bring it indoor? How to bring it indoor so that to cause least stress to it?

Where I live, the first frost for the last 15 years was as early as 6 October and as late as 19 November. Usually, it is somewhere in the middle of October.

[image: a shedded calamondin leaf]